# Event for when a view is no longer on top of the view stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Is there a way to tell when a view is no longer on top of the view stack? For example a modal view gets pushed on top of the view stack?

So I have a view with a table view, and there are some events that cause modals to be shown. When the modal is dismissed I want to reload the data in my table.

Is there an event I can subscribe for to achieve this? Maybe this is possible with KVO?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NSNotification system.

In your UITableViewController you will register for NSNotification (let's assume NSString *notifName = @"dismissmv"):

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hasDismissed:) notifName object:nil];
```

and implement

```
-(void)hasDismissed:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Then when you will dismiss the viewcontroller you'll post a notification:

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notifName object:nil];}];
```

Comment: I thought of something similar to this, but I have to post the notification manually in each view controller I display. There are a few different modals that are shown with the potential for more to be added in the future. I ended up using a custom notification that is posted when the data I'm interested in changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the order of a subview in a container view by using its `subviews` property.

From the documentation:

> @property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews
>
> Discussion
>
> You can use this property to retrieve the subviews associated with
>   your custom view hierarchies. The order of the subviews in the array
>   reflects their visible order on the screen, with the view at index 0
>   being the back-most view.
>
> For complex views declared in UIKit and other system frameworks, any
>   subviews of the view are generally considered private and subject to
>   change at any time. Therefore, you should not attempt to retrieve or
>   modify subviews for these types of system-supplied views. If you do,
>   your code may break during a future system update.